# Ping remote arbitrary command execution on linux

Tags: linux, ping, execution

I'm trying to execute code on a remote machine (virtual), which runs a webserver with a single POST form, intended to do a simple ping. On the other side is the following script (part of it):

exec("/bin/ping -c 4 ".$_POST["addr"]);

"addr" is where the data entered in the POST form goes. So basically it calls /bin/ping and appends whatever data I enter. The question is how can I leverage this to get a shell? I think that since the ping command runs with root privileges it should be fairly easy but I'm still new to this game and couldn't find any useful info on how to do this. Help will be very much appreciated :)

Comment: There's tons of questions that come from this but primarily why are you doing remote code execution through a browser with no input validation? Is there a purpose for this method or would you be open to more traditional methods of executing code on a remote host? (SSH being my primary thought)

Comment: it's an exercise, and that's the only way in the machine.

Comment: Did you try the classic "semicolon trick", `addr=; /bin/ls`? This would work if `exec` is executing the target via the shell.